# "Load more" implementations for sub-fields in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

Is there a preferred way to implement a load more functionality for sub-fields of the root type, for example, if I have this type definition

```
type Comment {
  author: String!
  content: String!
}

type Post {
  author: String!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  comments(last: Int = 10): [Comment!]!
}

type Query {
  post(id: Int!): Post
}
```

The client queries this field and can select the amount of post comments to fetch, then in the UI, there is a "Load more comments" button, which loads more comments.

My question is:
Do you use the same query to get more comments

```
post(postId: 1) {
  ...
  comments(last: 10, after: lastCommentCursor) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Or do you use a separate query to get more comments for that post

```
comments(postId: 1, last: 10, after: lastCommentCursor) {
  ...
}
```

I would assume the second approach is better, but I've seen the first one ( which, essentially fetches the same data for the post multiple times ) in a couple of projects. Did they use a bad practice or is there a legitimate reason to do it that way?